# Windows server last reboot time

Tags: windows

How can I find a Windows server's last reboot time, apart from 'net statistics server/workstation'?

Comment: In fact, net statistics does not seem to be showing the system boot time. http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-last-boot-time/#comment-24721

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/a/909172/33303 if you are interested in other acpi states like hibernation and standby

Answer (score 130):

Start → Run → `cmd.exe`:

```
systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"
```

Or for older OS versions (see comment):

```
systeminfo | find "System Up Time"
```

Comment: Works in Windows XP and I would assume Windows Server 2003, but doesn't work on Windows 2008 as it is now "System Boot Time".

Comment: This only works with English locale, see @user47994 for a language independent solution

Comment: "System Boot Time" works for Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"

Comment: And, this works remotely!

   systeminfo /s servername | ...

Comment: `systeminfo | find "Systemstartzeit"` on a German Windows Server 2022.

Comment: Confirmed working on Windows Server 2016 (as of 2023)

Answer (score 41):

Filter the System Event Log for Event ID 6009.

Comment: This is especially nice because if you keep a large enough event log, you will have a history of many previous reboots.

Answer (score 16):

open up the powershell command and run this to see all your history ... and no UI necessary :-)

```
get-eventlog System | where-object {$_.EventID -eq "6005"} | sort -desc TimeGenerated
```

Answer (score 12):

I use the [PsInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550.aspx) utility from Microsoft's Sysinternals package, which will give you output like this:

```
PsInfo v1.77 - Local and remote system information viewer
Copyright (C) 2001-2009 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

System information for \\JEFF-DELL:
Uptime:                    0 days 0 hours 33 minutes 27 seconds
Kernel version:            Microsoft Windows XP, Multiprocessor Free
Product type:              Professional
Product version:           5.1
Service pack:              3
Kernel build number:       2600
Registered organization:
Registered owner:          
IE version:                8.0000
System root:               C:\WINDOWS
Processors:                2
Processor speed:           2.3 GHz
Processor type:            Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6550  @
Physical memory:           3316 MB
Video driver:              Live Mesh Remote Desktop Mirror Driver
```

Comment: `psinfo uptime` will display just the uptime.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Server 2008, you can see the system uptime in hours on the "Task Manager" - "Performance" tab.
As far as I know, the "net statistics ..." way is the only true way on Windows 2003.

Comment: nice never knew that was there

Answer (score 8):

Using a wmi client.

```
C:\>wmic OS GET CSName,LastBootUpTime
CSName    LastBootUpTime 
SERVER  20101124084714.500000-360
```

Note: -360 = GMT-6

Answer (score 7):

**Last Time the System Booted**

My personal favorite is to use WMI and Win32_OperatingSystem properties/methods.  Here it is as an easy copy/paste one liner:

```
((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).ConvertToDateTime((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime))
```

Same thing, but easier for manual typing:

```
$obj = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
$obj.ConvertToDateTime($obj.LastBootUpTime)
```

Both options provide output like:

```
Monday, June 30, 2014 11:59:50 AM
```

**Length of System Up Time**

If you want to find out how long the system has been online you can do this (this is also an alternate code style):

```
$Obj = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$Obj.ConvertToDateTime($Obj.LocalDateTime) - $Obj.ConvertToDateTime($Obj.LastBootUpTime)
```

Which gives output like:

```
Days              : 7
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 59
Seconds           : 42
Milliseconds      : 745
Ticks             : 6119827457690
TotalDays         : 7.08313363158565
TotalHours        : 169.995207158056
TotalMinutes      : 10199.7124294833
TotalSeconds      : 611982.745769
TotalMilliseconds : 611982745.769
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Powershell

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime

CSName LastBootUpTime
Server 7/5/2014 6:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily open your task manager in performance tab under System find your "UpTime"!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since the last boot time is for troubleshooting a useful information, we automaticalley display it on `every server` as `background wallpaper`

[image]

[image]

**Howto**

- Using [Bginfo (Microsoft / Sysinternals)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo)
- Configure the wanted information
- Run as scheduled task:

  - command line: `Bginfo64.exe /silent /nolicprompt /timer:0`
  - trigger: on every user logon

Answer (score 2):

Following gives history of shutdown dates.

Refer [How to get the list of shutdown event with date?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/77aae737-7fe8-414b-b9a8-d06a7ac1f874/how-to-get-the-list-of-shutdown-event-with-date)

Filtering the `System` events with the event id `1074` in  `Eventvwr.exe` helped me