# Windows Server restart / shutdown history

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log

How can I easily see a history of every time my Windows Server has restarted or shutdown and the reason why, including user-initiated, system-initiated, and system crashed?

The Windows Event Log is an obvious answer but what is the complete list of events that I should view?

I found these posts that partially answer my question:

- [Windows server last reboot time](https://serverfault.com/questions/159612/windows-server-last-reboot-time) includes several answers that partially address the full restart history
- [View Shutdown Event Tracker logs under Windows Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/204417/view-shutdown-event-tracker-logs-under-windows-server-2008-r2) includes an additional event id
- [Event Log time when Computer Start up / boot up](https://serverfault.com/questions/401961/event-log-time-when-computer-start-up-boot-up) includes some of the same event ids

but those don't cover every scenario AFAIK and the info is hard to understand because it is spread across multiple answers.

I have several versions of Windows Server so a solution that works for at least versions 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, and 2012 R2 would be ideal.

Comment: In some situations Nirsoft's TurnedOnTimesView may be good enough. (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_turned_on_times.html) it shows reboots and shutdown times.

Comment: Do you use an external monitoring tool, .e.g., opsview, nagios, icinga, shinken? These tools store the monitoring results in a database and then you could check if servers were restarted and when,

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The clearest most succinct answer I could find is:

- [How To See PC Startup And Shutdown History In Windows](http://www.maketecheasier.com/see-pc-startup-and-shutdown-history-in-windows/)

which lists these event ids to monitor (quoted but edited and reformatted from article):

- [Event ID 6005](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6005&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033) ([alternate](https://web.archive.org/web/20161002145505/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6005&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033)): “The event log service was started.” This is synonymous to system startup.
- [Event ID 6006](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6006&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033) ([alternate](https://web.archive.org/web/20160512180234/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6006&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033)): “The event log service was stopped.” This is synonymous to system shutdown.
- [Event ID 6008](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=6008&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033/) ([alternate](https://web.archive.org/web/20161007144231/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=6008&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033/)): "The previous system shutdown was unexpected." Records that the system started after it was not shut down properly.
- [Event ID 6009](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6009&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033) ([alternate](https://web.archive.org/web/20161002234810/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6009&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033)): Indicates the Windows product name, version, build number, service pack number, and operating system type detected at boot time.
- Event ID 6013: Displays the uptime of the computer. There is no TechNet page for this id.

Add to that a couple more from the Server Fault answers listed in my OP:

- [Event ID 1074](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1074&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033) ([alternate](https://web.archive.org/web/20160519064523/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1074&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033)): "The process X has initiated the restart / shutdown of computer on behalf of user Y for the following reason: Z." Indicates that an application or a user initiated a restart or shutdown.
- [Event ID 1076](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1076&EvtSrc=USER32&LCID=1033) ([alternate](https://web.archive.org/web/20160523011320/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1076&EvtSrc=USER32&LCID=1033)): "The reason supplied by user X for the last unexpected shutdown of this computer is: Y."  Records when the first user with shutdown privileges logs on to the computer after an unexpected restart or shutdown and supplies a reason for the occurrence.

Did I miss any?

Comment: To differentiate between power loss and a reboot due to bugcheck, look for combination of Event ID 41 (source: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power) and Event ID 1001: (source: BugCheck).  Former without the latter indicates power loss or reset.

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you johnC. In the Includes/Excludes event ID's input field in the Filter Current Log window, I entered "6005, 6006, 6008, 6009, 6013, 1074, 1076" and it gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: You should probably add [`Kernel-General` with eventid `12`](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-12-source-Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General-eventno-11542-phase-1.htm), which is typically the first eventid to be logged after a reboot/reset etc and shows the actual "system start time", i.e.: _"The operating system started at system time ‎2017‎-‎09‎-‎19T02:46:06.582794900Z."_

Comment: The links in this answer are broken

Comment: I search but failed to find current Microsoft docs on event log codes so I created an issue in the Microsoft Docs github to garner advice / consensus on where to revive this content in the new MS docs regime, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/444. @tim-schmelter please upvote and add your thoughts.

Comment: I added alternate links to archive.org where all the missing Microsoft TechNet pages are still available.

Comment: Here is a PowerShell "one-liner" for that:  

Get-EventLog -LogName System |? {$_.EventID -in (6005,6006,6008,6009,1074,1076)} | ft TimeGenerated,EventId,Message -AutoSize -wrap

Comment: Event ID 41 "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

Answer (score 27):

Turning @user10082 [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/702828/windows-server-restart-shutdown-history#comment1273008_702829) into an answer. The proposed solution is a one-liner, as Powershell script:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System |? {$_.EventID -in (6005,6006,6008,6009,1074,1076)} | ft TimeGenerated,EventId,Message -AutoSize –wrap
```

Here is the output:

```
TimeGenerated         EventID Message
-------------         ------- -------
5/30/2021 11:23:16 AM    6005 The Event log service was started.
5/30/2021 11:23:16 AM    6009 Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 10.00. 19042  Multiprocessor Free.
5/30/2021 11:23:16 AM    6008 The previous system shutdown at 18:35:45 on ‎24/‎05/‎2021 was unexpected.
5/24/2021 11:55:45 AM    6005 The Event log service was started.
5/24/2021 11:55:45 AM    6009 Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 10.00. 19042  Multiprocessor Free.
5/24/2021 11:55:31 AM    6006 The Event log service was stopped.
5/24/2021 11:55:27 AM    1074 The process C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsAdminFlows.exe (DESKTOP) has
                              initiated the restart of computer DESKTOP on behalf of user DESKTOP\User
                              for the following reason: Other (Unplanned)
                               Reason Code: 0x0
                               Shutdown Type: restart
                               Comment:
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Deserves a lot more votes

Answer (score 4):

I would simply leave this as a comment since JohnC has basically covered everything, but I am not allowed to do so yet.

The events he described have been used for quite a while, so they will work for any of the OS you mentioned, as well as their desktop brethren.  The event ID pages He linked to, such as the one for [6006](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6006&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033) on TechNet, mention Windows Server 2003.

If there was an elegant shutdown, user initiated or otherwise, you should also see some [Event ID 7036](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349381(v=ws.10).aspx) telling you that various services "entered the stopped state."  As the machine starts up again, you will see more 7036s announcing that services are entering the running state.

Comment: You will also see a big block of event  ID 7036 if a service is repeatedly cycling states, so it isn't the best way to look for restarts.  You should look for [the events described](http://serverfault.com/a/702829/297063) by JohnC , first.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to accomplish activities from command line. Here's the beginning of a snippet you can leverage. This shows the most recent 30,000 system records and returns the reboots within those records.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 30000 | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6005}
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on [@JohnC](https://serverfault.com/users/232730/johnc) s answer and extending it

You could use an XML filter like:

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="System">
<Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog' or @Name='Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog'] and (EventID=1074 or EventID=1076 or EventID=6005 or EventID=6006 or EventID=6008) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="Setup">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog' or @Name='Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog'] and (EventID=1074 or EventID=1076 or EventID=6005 or EventID=6006 or EventID=6008) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog' or @Name='Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog'] and (EventID=1074 or EventID=1076 or EventID=6005 or EventID=6006 or EventID=6008) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power/Diagnostic">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (Level=1 ) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power/Thermal-Diagnostic">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (Level=1 ) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (Level=1 ) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='User32'] and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
<Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting'] and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 172800000]]]</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
```

You can replace 172800000 with the below values for the time range:

86400000 - Last 24 hours

172800000 - Last 2 Days

604800000 - Last 7 Days

This will show much more detail from the time when the server/pc went offline
It includes Kernel-Power, User32 and EventLog events.

Answer (score 1):

Short and concise one liner to get reboot and startup time of last 8 hours from a remote machine using SysInternals `psloglist` and the event id's from above:

```
psloglist \\computername -h 8 -i 41,1074,1076,6005,6006,6008,6013
```

The only thing missing (for me) is the event id for "logon dialog ready for user" equivalent. That seems to hard to find ([What can I query to see if Windows is booted and done with updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155443/what-can-i-query-to-see-if-windows-is-booted-and-done-with-updates))